# Triangle, with 3 levels, containing text on iOS

Tags: ios

I need some advice with my current project. The big problem being, I'm an android dev, helping out on iOS for the next few days.

I need to create a triangle, with 3 levels of text (as seen in the image below). Just adding labels at the different levels is leaving me with a lot of unused space. I have also though of using CGMutablePathRef to create a triangle, but it doesn't seem I can add a label to it, like you can to a CALayer. Or am I missing something?

Please, any advice would be appreciated (and example code even more so, as my iOS skills are still quite shocking).

[image: Example of triangle containing text, trying to achieve]

Regards

Comment: OK, I can't answer right this second but what you want is TextKit. It's a native iOS Framework for rendering text. You can also give is exclusion paths so you can render the text to fit in the triangle shape.

Comment: Thanks @Fogmeister, I'll look into it so long. From what I've read to far, seems like the right direction!

Comment: Any thoughts how I can add some support for iOS 6? Otherwise I'll just use labels for the few users left on iOS 6.